# In vapor what is the proper way to create an ephemeral service?

Tags: vapor

I am trying to make an ephemeral service that reinitializes on each request.

I think this is the write way of doing so

```
// Services File
struct StackOverflowUrlService: Service {
  let baseUrlString = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&site=stackoverflow&sort=activity"

  func requestForQuestions(for tag: String, timeAgo: TimeInterval) -> URLRepresentable {
    return baseUrlString + "&tagged=\(tag)" + "fromdate=\(timeAgo)"
  }
}

extension StackOverflowUrlService: ServiceType {
  static func makeService(for worker: Container) throws -> StackOverflowUrlService {
    return .init()
  }
}

//Configure File
services.register(StackOverflowUrlService.self)
```

is there a better way?